# How to show same product on two store with different attribute set in magento

Tags: magento

I have created 2 stores in magento e.g "http://example1.com" and "http://example2.com".

Also, I have 1 product, name is "product1". I have created 1 attribute "testimonial" for it. I want "testimonials" attribute only should display with "product1" on store "http://example1.com" and this attribute should not be visible with "product1" on store "http://example2.com".

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What you can do, is leave the value of some attributes blank for one store, and these will not show.

To clarify, you would use a unique set of attributes (with attributes A, B, C, D, E). For store 1 (the scope of attributes can be set to store view), you would set values for attributes A, B and E, for example, and leave the others blank. For store 2, you could set values for attributes B, C and D and leave the others blank. Only non-empty attributes will show for each store.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Attributes "Scope"? You can select "Globally", "Store View" or "Website" based. If you choose "Globally", any changes on the product in Store A, will affect also Store B. So, you should first try "Store View" or "Website" based options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I tried with "Store View" and "Website" option. But this only gives us flexibility to change attribute value like if we want to show different value on different store. I want to not show this attribute on one store and want to show this attribute on another store.